# Apache-poi “Compile error: Type mismatch”

Tags: java, apache-poi

I use Apache-poi 3.9 into my Struts 1.3.10 project.
I have two errors when i compile in this functionality:

```
private boolean parserHSSFSheet(HSSFSheet pageAccord, StringBuffer idPaa, StringBuffer idGroupe,
            StringBuffer idFournisseur, StringBuffer idFamille, StringBuffer periode, Map<Integer, Marque> mapMarque,
            Map<Integer, Ristournable> mapRistournable, Map<Integer, PerimetreProduitEnum> mapTypeDeclaration,
            Map<Integer, FamilleDeProduitsNomenclature> mapFamille, Map<Integer, String> mapMarqueProduit,
            TreeMap<Integer, TreeMap<Integer, BigDecimal>> mapColonneAdherentMontant,
            TreeMap<Integer, BigDecimal> mapAdherentQuantite) throws Exception {

...   

for (Iterator<HSSFRow> rit = pageAccord.rowIterator(); rit.hasNext();) {
    HSSFRow row = (HSSFRow) rit.next();

    String typeCellule = "";

    for (Iterator<HSSFCell> cit = (Iterator<HSSFCell>) row.cellIterator(); cit.hasNext();) {
        HSSFCell cell = cit.next();

        if (cell.getCellNum() == ((short) 0)) {

...

}
```

***Errors:***

`pageAccord.rowIterator();`

> Type mismatch: cannot convert from Iterator to Iterator

And

`(Iterator<HSSFCell>) row.cellIterator();`

> Cannot cast from Iterator to Iterator

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you seen the docs?? https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/hssf/usermodel/HSSFSheet.html says that `rowIterator` returns `java.util.Iterator<Row>` so you cannot cast it "onwards". The same is regarding cell etc.

change

```
Iterator<HSSFRow> rit = pageAccord.rowIterator(); rit.hasNext();
```

To

```
Iterator<Row> rit = pageAccord.rowIterator(); rit.hasNext();
```

And do the same for the `cellIterator`

Second cast, `Cell` into `HSSFCell` should work if iterator indeed will return compatibile type with `HSSFCell`.

Answer (score 2):

As per the API docs a call to

- `pageAccord.rowIterator()` returns a `java.util.Iterator<Row>`. See [here](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/hssf/usermodel/HSSFSheet.html#rowIterator%28%29).
- `row.cellIterator()` returns a `java.util.Iterator<Cell>`. See [here](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/hssf/usermodel/HSSFRow.html#cellIterator%28%29).

Both `Row` and `Cell` are only interfaces. Still I would work with those when possible and defer the explicit downcasting to places where this is actually necessary (and allowed).

**Thus:** Amend your iterators to comply with the types listed above (this could also mean using a generic `Iterator<?>` in places) and only downcast later (such as in your `HSSFRow row = (HSSFRow) rit.next();`).

Answer (score -2):

**Please find the below program for the quick solution**

```
workbook = WorkbookFactory.create(new FileInputStream(envFilePath + "\\"+ listOfFiles[i].getName()));
                            // Get the first sheet.
                            Sheet sheet = workbook.getSheetAt(0);

                            // Get the first cell.
                            Row row = sheet.getRow(0);
                            Cell cell = row.getCell(0);
```

**Test program which can help you**

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;

import org.apache.poi.openxml4j.exceptions.InvalidFormatException;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Cell;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Row;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Sheet;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Workbook;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.WorkbookFactory;

public class TestExcelFile {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String envFilePath = System.getenv("AZURE_FILE_PATH");

        // upload list of files/directory to blob storage
        File folder = new File(envFilePath);
        File[] listOfFiles = folder.listFiles();

        for (int i = 0; i < listOfFiles.length; i++) {
            if (listOfFiles[i].isFile()) {
                System.out.println("File " + listOfFiles[i].getName());

                Workbook workbook;
                try {
                        workbook = WorkbookFactory.create(new FileInputStream(envFilePath + "\\"+ listOfFiles[i].getName()));
                        // Get the first sheet.
                        Sheet sheet = workbook.getSheetAt(0);

                        // Get the first cell.
                        Row row = sheet.getRow(0);
                        Cell cell = row.getCell(0);

                        // Show what is being read.
                        System.out.println(cell.toString());
                        for (Cell cell1 : row) {
                            System.out.println(cell1.toString());
                        }
                } catch (InvalidFormatException | IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: As per http://poi.apache.org/spreadsheet/quick-guide.html#FileInputStream don't use an `InputStream` if you have a `File`!

Comment: This problem resolved from 3.14 version of POI dependency, if some one use below version then this is the solution. I am using the 3.9 Library to my project, File not possible.